# Why does each angular app have its own copy of node_modules

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-modules

I'm a noob to Angular development. I installed node.js and did a global install of the Angular cli (npm install -g @angular/cli). Nevertheless, I also have to npm install angular (without the -g option) in every Angular project. This creates a node_modules directory in the project and installs a LOT of files in that directory. Files that take up a lot of disk space.

Is there a way to do a global install of @angular/cli @angular/common, etc., then use that one set of global files in my projects?

I haven't found any documentation for doing so.

Thanks.

Comment: Node.js was designed this way from the beginning because the "a lot" of disk space is very little space if you consider the sizes of modern disks. The reason why each project have its own node_modules folder is to avoid versioning issues. If you look inside node_modules you will see that each module can themselves have their own node_modules folder. For example `node_modules/url/node_modules`. Don't worry about it. The disk space is insignificant even when it's "a lot".

Comment: I haven't been in a similar situation before! but I think as the first step in the diagnose is to check the accessibility of the "path" to the "node_modules" once you have node.js installed. I think this could be the source of the problem.

Comment: Have I been doing it wrong? I have four Angular projects. Together, just the node_modules folders take up 2Gb and contain 200,000 files. Sure, I can always get a bigger disk (work computer), but all that duplication just seems wasteful. I appreciate the versioning issue. We had a hard time telling what apps were in production, staging, and dev when the institutional knowledge retired. Proper versioning would have obviated that problem.

Comment: I have the same question. I like the comment by @NoNameProvided
"If you use the newest NPM version then all packages are installed once and then symlinked." I need to find out how to do that. I have about 20 projects each of which their node_modules are 0.5GB - > 1.5GB. It just seems wasteful